# How to change path to android folder in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to use React Native for my existing android app but I don't want to copy and paste the project into android folder created by React native, instead I want to set its path to the location where my existing android project resides. How to do that?

Comment: try `react-native link` command

Comment: react-native link is for "installing" plugin (in the compilation process) you download from npm/github. no relation with this

Comment: Waheed, react-native and Android native code is two different things. if you have an app write in java you have to rewrite it from scratch in javascript in react-native standard